# segmentation fault (core dumped) when changing string characters

Tags: c

Why changing string characters causes segmentation fault(core dumped):

```
char *str = "string";
str[0] = 'S'; //segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Comment: Please use search first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, declare your string in the following way instead

```
  char str[] = "string";
```

The reason why you should do this is because of the [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Creating a string with pointers will make your string locate at the `read only` memory part, so you cannot modify it, whereas another way will also make a copy of your string on the stack. Also check [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: You cannot say both "undefined behavior" and "**will make**" (a definitive statement).   The point of "undefined behavior" is that anything can happen, and nothing is required to happen.   It is *likely* that your string will be located in read-only memory, but not required.

Comment: @abelenky Thanks for pointing out, I'm not a native english speaker, and the undefined behavior says that the one like the question is one of the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`char *str = "string";` points to a **read-only** part of memory and because of that the string **can't be changed**.

You need to declare an **array** instead of a **pointer** which points to an array if you want to change the array like this

```
char str[] = "string";
```